# Magento Action Controller going to 404

Tags: magento, controller, http-status-code-404

For a custom module I created a new actioncontroller. But it doesn't execute. It's returns only a 404.
I tried already some solutions from stackoverflow, but no one is working for me. :(

Urls I tried to call my action:

- http://pharmaprofit.dev/index.php/medipim/sync/
- http://pharmaprofit.dev/medipim/sync/
- http://pharmaprofit.dev/medipim/sync/index

Can you take a look in my code? Maybe it's just a typo I didn't see.

Crmart/Medipim/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Crmart_Medipim>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Crmart_Medipim>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <medipim>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Crmart_Medipim</module>
                    <frontName>medipim</frontName>
                </args>
            </medipim>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Crmart/Medipim/controllers/SyncController.php

```
class Crmart_Medipim_SyncController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
        //
        echo 'hello world!';
    }

    public function nowAction()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

app/etc/modules/Crmart_Medipim.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Crmart_Medipim>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Crmart_Medipim>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: Which 404 page?  Magento has many (http://alanstorm.com/magentos_many_404_pages) and knowing which page will help people solve your problem.  Also, I'd give the Magento Better404 module a try (http://alanstorm.com/magento-404-debug).  It adds debugging messages to your 404 page that help find common problems. (self links, but useful self links :))

Comment: Thx for this great plugin!Everything seems fine, but I don't understand why I can't see my 'echo'. It's just like it's not executing the code in my actions. [view my screenshot](http://f.cl.ly/items/2R3t3d180G11331E0A1u/Image%202014-12-17%20at%208.46.14%20am.png)

Comment: Ok, now I take a look in my browser console and find this `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS`error.

Comment: Ignore last comment. It's just a chrome caching error. That's fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Fixed! 
I had enabled to view storecodes in my url.
So when I enter `http://pharmaprofit.dev/nl/medipim/sync/now` instead of `http://pharmaprofit.dev/medipim/sync/now` , it's working!

Answer (score 0):

Plug-in files created correctly check once below steps for you plug-in works.

1. Check that plugin is successfully registered or not form admin section 
   Admin ->System->configuration->Advance 
   check plugin is listed here
2. open the app/etc/local.xml and check the below line
   `<disable_local_modules>false</disable_local_modules>`
   the value must be false otherwise plugin will not work

Comment: Thx. But it's fixed. Check my answer in another comment. ;-)